# Python: sending and receiving large files over POST using cherrypy

Tags: python, http, post, upload, cherrypy

I have a cherrypy web server that needs to be able to receive large files over http post. I have something working at the moment, but it fails once the files being sent gets too big (around 200mb). I'm using curl to send test post requests, and when I try to send a file that's too big, curl spits out "The entity sent with the request exceeds the maximum allowed bytes." Searching around, this seems to be an error from cherrypy.

So I'm guessing that the file being sent needs to be sent in chunks? I tried something with mmap, but I couldn't get it too work. Does the method that handles the file upload need to be able to accept the data in chunks too?

Comment: According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cherrypy-users/xGvxBGgQ90k), you could try setting the config value server.max_request_body_size to something higher?

Comment: @jobby: You really should post that as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 7):

I took [`DirectToDiskFileUpload`](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/DirectToDiskFileUpload) as a starting point. The changes it makes to handle big uploads are:

1. `server.max_request_body_size` to `0` (default 100MB),
2. `server.socket_timeout` to `60` (default 10s),
3. `response.timeout` to `3600` (default 300s),
4. Avoiding double copy by using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`.

There are also some useless actions taken to supposedly avoid holding upload in memory, which disable standard CherryPy body processing and use `cgi.FieldStorage` manually instead. It is useless because there is `cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part.maxrambytes`.

> The threshold of bytes after which point the `Part` will store its data
>   in a file instead of a string. Defaults to 1000, just like the `cgi` module in
>   Python's standard library.

I've experimented with the following code (run by Python 2.7.4, CherryPy 3.6) and 1.4GB file. Memory usage (in *gnome-system-monitor*) never reached out 10MiB. According to the number of bytes actually written to the disk, `cat /proc/PID/io`'s `write_bytes` is almost the size of the file. With standard `cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part` and `shutil.copyfileobj` it is obviously doubled.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os
import tempfile

import cherrypy


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8,
    # remove any limit on the request body size; cherrypy's default is 100MB
    'server.max_request_body_size' : 0,
    # increase server socket timeout to 60s; cherrypy's defult is 10s
    'server.socket_timeout' : 60
  }
}


class NamedPart(cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part):

  def make_file(self):
    return tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

cherrypy._cpreqbody.Entity.part_class = NamedPart


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <body>
        <form action='upload' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          File: <input type='file' name='videoFile'/> <br/>
          <input type='submit' value='Upload'/>
        </form>
      </body>
      </html>
    '''

  @cherrypy.config(**{'response.timeout': 3600}) # default is 300s
  @cherrypy.expose()
  def upload(self, videoFile):
    assert isinstance(videoFile, cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part)

    destination = os.path.join('/home/user/', videoFile.filename)

    # Note that original link will be deleted by tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile
    os.link(videoFile.file.name, destination)

    # Double copy with standard ``cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part``
    #import shutil
    #with open(destination, 'wb') as f:
    #  shutil.copyfileobj(videoFile.file, f)

    return 'Okay'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Answer (score 0):

Huge file uploads always problematic. What would you do when connection closes in the middle of uploading? Use chunked file upload method instead.